# Webdriver Actionchains - click on the next page doesn't work

Tags: selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup, selenium-chromedriver, web-crawler

I am new here and I tried to write a code that should go through all of die 3090 pages and extract the information given in the table (box-b).

But it doesn't work. It seems to stay on the first page and it extracts those informations over and over.

If any of you has an idea how I can fix it please help me :)

Lara

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

url = "https://www.dieversicherer.de/versicherer/auto---reise/typklassenabfrage#orderBy=kh&orderDirection=ASC"

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/laraschneider/Downloads/chromedriver')
driver.get(url)

time.sleep(5)

html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
number = 0
while number < 3090:
    results_html = soup.find_all('div', "ttw-entry__box-b")

    results = list()

    for result in results_html:
        results.append(result.text)

    for t in results:
        print(t)

    time.sleep(5)

    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/main/div/div[5]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/button[2]/div")
    action = ActionChains(driver)
    action.move_to_element(element)
    action.click(element).perform()


    number = number+1
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)` instead of `ActionChains`. Here is the full code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

url = "https://www.dieversicherer.de/versicherer/auto---reise/typklassenabfrage#orderBy=kh&orderDirection=ASC"

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/laraschneider/Downloads/chromedriver')
driver.get(url)

time.sleep(5)

html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
number = 0
while number < 3090:
    results_html = soup.find_all('div', "ttw-entry__box-b")

    results = list()

    for result in results_html:
        results.append(result.text)

    for t in results:
        print(t)

    time.sleep(5)

    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/main/div/div[5]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/button[2]/div')
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
    number = number+1
```

Comment: Thank you, but it still doesn't work. It still extracts the table from the first page. Do you have any other idea?